# How to disable MD RAID or prevent degraded arrays from starting. (Centos 6.4)

Tags: linux, centos6, mdadm

I am trying to disable software RAID at boot time. My ultimate goal is to prevent the system from starting raid arrays that are in a degraded state.

rd_NO_MD is present on the kernel command line by default and does not disable raid.

I've removed all the raid stuff from the initrd using dracut.

The RAID system seems to come alive inside "start_udev" run from "rc.sysinit".

How to I supress this? Or, alternatively, what is the corrent way to prevent degraded arrays from starting?

Comment: /lib/udev/rules.d/64-md-raid.rules
    /lib/udev/rules.d/65-md-incremental.rules